# Inductive or Deductive Reasoning

Tags: mathematics, algebra

Russell wanted to impress his coworkers. At a meeting, he announces that he can predict anyone's birthday if they tell him their *birthday number*. To get this famous *birthday number*, he asked everyone to do the following steps:

> Take the month of your birthday (1 for January, 2 for February, etc.)
>   then multiply by 5
>   then add 7
>   then multiply it by 4
>   then add 13
>   then multiply by 5
>   then add the day of your birthday

Dave announced his birthday now was 612. Ricky said his was 1129 and Mike said his was 1436. Russell said "Well Dave, your birthday is April 7th. Ricky, yours is September 24th and Mike, you were born on the last day of the year, December 31st."

Make a conjecture about how Russell determines the birthday by examining the numbers.

**How to solve this?**

Comment: Mathematics problem rather than puzzle. The "Make a conjecture" sounds to me like it's from a schoolteacher, so I reckon about 80% chance this is *actually someone's mathematics homework*.

Comment: That would be hilarious haha.

Answer (score 5):

You just need to reverse the process to get back the original values

> x=month and y=day
>  I will use dave's info for the calculation
>  ((x * 5 + 7) * 4 + 13) * 5 + y = 612
>  (20x + 41) * 5 + y = 612
>  100x + 205 + y = 612
>  100x + y = 407
>  we can now easily deduce that x is 4(April) and y is 7

Answer (score 4):

Notice the pattern.

Get the month

> Subtract two and get the month.
> $612$ =  6 - 2 = 4 (April)
> $1129$ = 11 -2 = 9 (September)
> $1436$ = 14 -2 = 12 (December)

For the day

> Subtract 5 and get the day.
> $612$ = 12 - 5 = 7 (7th of April)
> $1129$ = 29 - 5 = 24 (24th of September)
> $1436$ = 36 - 5 = 31 (31st of December)

*However there might some be rare cases where it might be difficult to use this. You'll have to see to that. In places where this doesn't work, you can reverse the equation and find it out by hand*

I say rare because the calculations that Russell asks a person to do before giving the number makes it highly unlikely for such a case.

Either way you're covered :)